# What data structure is better to use for storing and sorting <int, int> structure?

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures

I have such structure with ids and their count:

```
product[38] = 10;
product[22] = 7;
product[39] = 18;
```

I need to use some structure for it. But not sure what should serve better (`map`, `unordered_map`, `set`, `vector`).

I was trying to use:

```
map<int, int> product;
```

But not sure is it the best choice. The only thing that I should do with it - sorting.

As a result I need:

```
product[39] = 18;
product[38] = 10;
product[22] = 7;
```

**UPD:** Sort by value.

Comment: Are those sorted by key or value?

Comment: I guess you need look-up by key as well? Otherwise there would be no reason to prefer a map over a set.

Comment: Are the ids consecutive?

Comment: Do you want to add all the values, then sort once, then use? Or do you want to keep adding values and be sure they are kept sorted in the container at all times?

Comment: @sftrabbit Updated a question

Comment: @larsmans no, they are at random order

Comment: @jogojapan Yes, I want to add all values at for loop and then sort once by value.

Comment: So, key by id, but sort by count, is that what this all boils down to?

Comment: @WhozCraig Key - int id, value - int count. Sort by value.

Comment: @viakondratiuk ok. but you also never answered Jogo's question above? Is this a sort-as-needed thing? In other words, do you just need the sorted sequence on-demand, as opposed to continually maintained? Finally, is it required the sort be *stable*? I.e., if (1,20), (2,10), (3,10) are your tuples, must the sort-by-value results maintain the relative placement of (2,10) and (3,10) to each other, though both will now come before (1,20) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Just check above, I answered Jogo question. All I need is: I have coming product ids like this: 34,22,12,34,12,48. I need to show the most frequent of them. I decided to create such structure as associative array `product[38]=5`. I will have for loop and increase count every time `product[38]++`. After it I want to sort it by value and on the top of data structure get the most frequent ids.

Comment: @viakondratiuk ok. I think I understand. yet another answer posted below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to make a struct or [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) and sore them in [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> product;

product.push_back(std::pair<int,int>(38, 27));
product.push_back(std::pair<int,int>(22, 7));
product.push_back(std::pair<int,int>(39, 18));
```

sort by value:

```
std::sort(product.begin(), product.end(), 
  [](const std::pair<int,int>& p1, const std::pair<int,int>& p2){ return p1.second < p2.second; });
```

Comment: I have product ids which come in random order and I increment their count as `product[38]++`. How I can increase pair value?

Comment: you could use find,find_if to locate the element and operate on the pair

Answer (score 6):

A `std::map` is fine in this case, considering that you are mapping IDs to a count.

For future reference:

[image]

Comment: How to implement sorting for it?

Comment: @viakondratiuk maps is sorted by key.

Comment: @juanchopanza I need to sort by value

Comment: @billz: `std::multimap` seems like a good option in that case. However, since the question has been updated asking for sort-by-value, my answer is moot.  I rather doubt that key collision could occur, due  to the term _ID_, which suggests a unique value to me.

Answer (score 1):

If i had to do this in the confines of your proposed usage (maintain a key-map for quick counter updates, then dump a sorted result), I would likely use an unordered map and a pointer vector. With this I'm assuming the primary reason you want some indexed-key soluton in the first place is to make data processing significantly quicker when updating counts.

In other words, you're looking to get a good speed-bump out of code that does this:

```
++product[ id ]; // increment counter for product 'id' in our keyed-container.
```

But still be able to report output sorted not on id, but rather on the accumulated count of each id. That being said, the following, though a little dense, will do *exactly* that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef std::unordered_map<int, int> Products;
    Products product;

    // fill with random data for our test.
    std::srand((unsigned)time(0));
    for (int i=1;i<20;++i)
    {
        product[i] = rand() % 50 + 1;
        cout << setw(3) << i << " ==> " << product[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;


    // now setup a one-shot sort. we're using a vector of
    //  pointers to our map value type
    std::vector<const Products::value_type*> data;
    data.reserve(product.size());
    std::transform(product.begin(), product.end(), std::back_inserter(data),
                   [](const Products::value_type& obj) { return std::addressof(obj); });

    // sort the vector by value (second)
    std::stable_sort(data.begin(), data.end(),
                     [](const Products::value_type* left, const Products::value_type* right)
                     { return left->second < right->second; });

    // results are in the vector as pointers. the original map is unchanged.
    for (auto ptr : data)
        cout << setw(3) << ptr->first << " ==> " << ptr->second << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

**Sample Run**

```
  1 ==> 42
  2 ==> 18
  3 ==> 35
  4 ==> 1
  5 ==> 20
  6 ==> 25
  7 ==> 29
  8 ==> 9
  9 ==> 13
 10 ==> 15
 11 ==> 6
 12 ==> 46
 13 ==> 32
 14 ==> 28
 15 ==> 12
 16 ==> 42
 17 ==> 46
 18 ==> 43
 19 ==> 28
 20 ==> 37

  4 ==> 1
 11 ==> 6
  8 ==> 9
 15 ==> 12
  9 ==> 13
 10 ==> 15
  2 ==> 18
  5 ==> 20
  6 ==> 25
 14 ==> 28
 19 ==> 28
  7 ==> 29
 13 ==> 32
  3 ==> 35
 20 ==> 37
  1 ==> 42
 16 ==> 42
 18 ==> 43
 12 ==> 46
 17 ==> 46
```

I've used this method in the past because it is swimmingly-efficient for more complex structures that are expensive to copy into temporary containers for sorting. That the ending pointer-vector references the *real* data in the map is a nicety that, while probably overkill for this specific problem, certainly has reaps of benefits as a general solution.

That being said, if all you want is an int-to-int dump, sorted on second-int rather than your map key, this will likewise do the trick, though it does replicate data out of your container to accomplish the end-goal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef std::unordered_map<int, int> Products;
    Products product;

    // fill with random data for our test.
    std::srand((unsigned)time(0));
    for (int i=1;i<20;++i)
    {
        product[i] = rand() % 50 + 1;
        cout << setw(3) << i << " ==> " << product[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // copy the values from the map to a sort bed.
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> vals;
    std::copy(product.begin(), product.end(), back_inserter(vals));
    std::stable_sort(vals.begin(), vals.end(),
        [](const std::pair<int,int>& left, const std::pair<int,int>& right)
        { return left.second < right.second; });

    // dump to stdout
    for (auto val : vals)
        cout << setw(3) << val.first << " ==> " << val.second << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
  1 ==> 48
  2 ==> 30
  3 ==> 25
  4 ==> 32
  5 ==> 34
  6 ==> 21
  7 ==> 26
  8 ==> 6
  9 ==> 50
 10 ==> 28
 11 ==> 50
 12 ==> 32
 13 ==> 35
 14 ==> 17
 15 ==> 33
 16 ==> 30
 17 ==> 13
 18 ==> 1
 19 ==> 50

 18 ==> 1
  8 ==> 6
 17 ==> 13
 14 ==> 17
  6 ==> 21
  3 ==> 25
  7 ==> 26
 10 ==> 28
  2 ==> 30
 16 ==> 30
  4 ==> 32
 12 ==> 32
 15 ==> 33
  5 ==> 34
 13 ==> 35
  1 ==> 48
  9 ==> 50
 11 ==> 50
 19 ==> 50
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do in following way:

create a class/struct of two int member

```
struct int_pair{
     int key;
     int value;
}
```

then create a

```
   vector<int_pair> myvector;
```

then create two bool compare functions:

```
 bool sort_by_key(int_pair left, int_pair right){
      return left.key<right.key;
 }

 bool sort_by_value(int_pair left, int_pair right){
     return left.value<right.value;
 }
```

then sort using std::sort and those bool functions.

```
 std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), sort_by_key);
```

p.s: sorry about the formatting. typing from mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use [boost.bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html). Its is a little work to understand it but its worth and I think its fits exactly your use case.